# コマンドプロンプトにパスを渡すとエラーが起きる

Tags: コマンドプロンプト

windows10のコマンドプロンプトでカレントディレクトリを変更するために

```
C:\Users\   >cd"C:\Program Files\MeCab\bin"
```

を実行したところ、

```
"ファイル名、ディレクトリ名、またはボリューム ラベルの構文が間違っています。"
```

とエラーが出て困っています。

\は半角￥に置換しています

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cd` コマンドの後に指定するパスとの間に半角スペースを入力してください。

```
cd "C:\Program Files\MeCab\bin"
```